# Install ubuntu server by flashing disk drive

Tags: server, headless

I wonder if there is a way to install ubuntu server(or any other linux distribution) just by flashing drive and plugging it into new machine(configuring it by conf files beforehand).
I found way for raspberry pi here https://dev.to/henri_rion/9-steps-raspberry-pi-headless-setup-with-ubuntu-21-04-3el3
but I want to use it for different machine(intel nuc), so looking for something similar

Comment: In order to "flash" install to a nuc, you would need an image that is already compiled and customized for that specific hardware configuration...and already has a login created for you to use. The Ubuntu developers decided against tediously creating thousands of images for thousands of hardware configurations on amd64 in favor of the single interactive LiveUSB installer that probes hardware and installs/configures what is needed for that specific hardware/network/locale set.

Comment: You can create a custom Ubuntu image on a different amd64 machine and "flash" (`dd`) that image onto your disk.